# How to use LiteIDE for a Go project?

Tags: ide, go, liteide

I've installed the LiteIDE IDE for Go. I create a new Go project, but I when I try to run it I get:

```
<action id="Run" cmd="$(TARGETPATH)" args="$(TARGETARGS)"> <start=" " workdir=""/> <error msg="process failed to start" /> </action>
```

I guess I need to configure LiteIDE, but I don't how and I did not find any relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

1. Create Go1 Project in YOUR_PATH
2. Import  project (in projects window) and set custom GOOPATH to YOUR_PATH.
3. Set active project in the context menu on YOUR_PATH.